# "The distance is great" vs. "high" vs. "large"

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, collocation

I don't want to change the structure of the sentence. So please tell me which adjective works better in this sentence — *great, high* or *large*.

> Due to the resolution of cameras, vehicles are not visible in regions where the vehicles' distance to camera is **great**.

Comment: The sentence as it stands is tautologous, really just explaining what resolving power is - it doesn't matter what the optical objects are, vehicles, ants or stars. Also, many would prefer 'because of' here: Because of the poor resolving power of the cameras involved, vehicles over 8 miles away will not be imaged.

Comment: _Great_ is a general modifier that can be attached to almost any quantified expression, but _high_ involves an `UP/DOWN` metaphor of some kind, most likely a vertically-oriented scale of measurement, and _large_ refers most commonly to some metaphor of quantity or volume, rather than of length per se. So, all things considered, I agree with @EdwinAshworth that the sentence is ill-constructed (if it's intended to be understood, anyway), and with @JamesRobinson that _substantial_ is a better word in context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is a little awkward, but I'd choose large, or maybe great -- both work.
There is probably an error in the sentence too:

```
... the vehicles' distance to camera is large.
```

Should probably be:

```
... the vehicles' distance to **the** camera is large.
```

It is possible that "distance to camera" is the name of a specific metric. If so it might work as:

```
 ... the vehicles' distance-to-camera is large.
```

If it is such a measure "large" would be preferred.

Either way the sentence is a little awkward.

Answer (score 2):

Of the three listed *great* seems best, though personally I would opt for *substantial*.